# google map api v3 background color

Tags: google-maps

I have placed a custom map png on google map.  I have removed everything from google maps to only display my custom map.  The background color is a light blue and I want to change it to white. Here is the code:

```
function initialize() {

  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(39, -98.5);
  var myOptions = {
    maxZoom: 4,
    minZoom: 4,
    zoom: 4,

    panControl: false,
    draggable: false,
        center: myLatLng,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  var mapStyles = [
  {
    featureType: "all",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }]
    }];

map.setOptions({styles: mapStyles});
}
```

It only flashes white then changes to a light blue.  How do I set it to white or transparent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

although you removed everything there still be blank tiles present.

You may try to hide those tiles, the following CSS works for me:

```
  /*the desired background for the map*/
#map_canvas{background-color:#fff !important}

  /*hides the tiles (and maybe more^^)*/
#map_canvas div div div div div div img{visibility:hidden}
```

Answer (score 27):

You can just set `backgroundColor: 'none'`

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {lat: 41.876, lng: -87.624},
    backgroundColor: 'none'
  });
```

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, this still works in 2020 with the most recent version of GoogleMaps.